# Give 2 Methods to message.content for a discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot to filter out bad words, but the problem is that I only can have 1 method after `Message.content` in which case I got `.toLowerCase` but I also want to make it so that it reads the word wherever in the sentence it was used, only important stuff I got right now

```js
client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'hello')
  message.channel.send('yoyo ' + '<@' + message.author + '>');

 
});
```

Comment: Well, I tried to do message.content.includes.toLowerCase but that doesnt work

Comment: Not yet, I've only tried it with the current code as shown above, i just want to see if my bot responds whenever I use a word in my sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, is this what you would be looking for? This allows you to look for lowercase letters anywhere in your sentence.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('hello'))
    message.channel.send('yoyo ' + '<@' + message.author + '>');

});
```

Comment: This did exactly what i wanted, only problem is that now when i entered "hello" it just kept spamming with @'s 
EDIT: This was my own fault, accidentally made it loop the bot by adding 
    message.channel.send('yoyo ' + '<@' + message.author + '>');

 twice